# MatSnackBar error when using TestBed component creation and undefined fixture

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, jestjs

**[CONTEXT]:** So here's the thing. I'm currently trying to build some unit tests for a component in angular 8 using jest, jasmine and angular TestBed module.
This component is pretty basic, one datable, data table fetched from an API, and possibility to edit the data.

Here's an sample of my spec file:

```
jest.mock('../../../services/external-actors.service');
// jest.mock('@angular/material/snack-bar');
jest.mock('@fuse/services/translation-loader.service');
jest.mock('../../../services/snackbar.service');
jest.mock('../../../services/permission/permission.service');

describe('ListExternalActorsComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                MatSnackBarModule,
                MatTableModule,
                MatMenuModule,
                TranslateModule.forRoot({
                    loader: TranslateFakeLoader,
                }),
            ],
            providers: [
                MatSnackBar,
                { provide: MatDialog },
                // { provide: TranslateService },
                { provide: FuseTranslationLoaderService },
                { provide: SnackbarService },
                { provide: PermissionService },
                { provide: ExternalActorsService },
            ],
            declarations: [
                ListExternalActorsComponent
            ],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
        }).compileComponents();


        beforeEach(inject([], () => { 
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListExternalActorsComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            fixture.detectChanges();
        }));
        afterEach(() => {
            fixture.destroy();
        });
    }));

    it('should instantiate', inject([], () => {
        expect(fixture).toBeDefined();
        console.log('FIXTURE >>>>>', fixture);
        console.log('COMPONENT >>>>>', component);
    }));
});
```

**[PROBLEMS]:**

1. The sample of code above is working when I launch my test but `fixture` and `component` are *undefined* and `expect(fixture).toBeDefined();` throw an error.
2. When I try to move my component creation inside of the `it()` part like this:

```
it('should instantiate', inject([], () => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListExternalActorsComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.autoDetectChanges():
        console.log('FIXTURE >>>>>', fixture);
        console.log('COMPONENT >>>>>', component);
    }));
```

I got the error below caused by the component creation line (`TestBed.createComponent(ListExternalActorsComponent)`):

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ListExternalActorsComponent -> MatSnackBar]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ListExternalActorsComponent -> MatSnackBar]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSnackBar!Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSnackBar!

      at NullInjector.get (../packages/core/src/di/injector_compatibility.ts:205:21) [angular]
      at resolveToken (../packages/core/src/di/injector.ts:315:20) [angular]
      at tryResolveToken (../packages/core/src/di/injector.ts:257:12) [angular]
      at StaticInjector.get (../packages/core/src/di/injector.ts:146:14) [angular]
      at resolveToken (../packages/core/src/di/injector.ts:315:20) [angular]
      at tryResolveToken (../packages/core/src/di/injector.ts:257:12) [angular]
      at StaticInjector.get (../packages/core/src/di/injector.ts:146:14) [angular]
      at resolveNgModuleDep (../packages/core/src/view/ng_module.ts:125:25) [angular]
      at NgModuleRef_.get (../packages/core/src/view/refs.ts:507:12) [angular]
      at resolveDep (../packages/core/src/view/provider.ts:423:43) [angular]
      at createClass (../packages/core/src/view/provider.ts:283:24) [angular]
      at createDirectiveInstance (../packages/core/src/view/provider.ts:136:20) [angular]
      at createViewNodes (../packages/core/src/view/view.ts:303:28) [angular]
      at createRootView (../packages/core/src/view/view.ts:210:3) [angular]
      at callWithDebugContext (../packages/core/src/view/services.ts:630:23) [angular]
      at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (../packages/core/src/view/services.ts:122:10) [angular]
      at ComponentFactory_.create (../packages/core/src/view/refs.ts:93:27) [angular]
      at initComponent (../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:589:28) [angular]
      at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:117:43) [angular]
      at Object.onInvoke (../packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts:273:25) [angular]
      at NgZone.run (../packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts:171:50) [ProxyZone]
      at TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:593:56) [ProxyZone]
      at Function.TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:232:36) [ProxyZone]
      at app/app/admin/external-actors/list-external-actors/list-external-actors.spec.ts:61:27 [ProxyZone]
      at TestBedViewEngine.execute (../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:477:15) [ProxyZone]
      at ../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:668:53 [ProxyZone]
      at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:117:43) [ProxyZone]
```

Any ideas which way of creating component with TestBed is the best/should be used and why this lovely MatSnackBar isn't working in some cases ?

Thanks